Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: error: 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h' file not found
I've run
flutter clean & flutter pub get

many times
and when I run flutter build ios it will complain about
/Users/john.z/Desktop/frontendRepos/flutter_alp_invoicing/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridg
    ing-Header.h:1:9: error: 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h' file not found
    #import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"


and I search from  the file system, it really not exists. I think it's created by flutter automatically. but why it's missing
I also run the following command many times
cd ios
pod install

besides, my Podfile looks like this
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end


the Generated.xcconfig file always be created after I run flutter build ios.... it's not as the docs said after I run flutter pub get, it's kind of a mess.
so I need to run flutter build ios first to generate the Generated.xcconfig, then I can run pod install. but however the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h file is still missing.
I also tried recreate the ios folder
I've searched the internet and asked the chatgpt, still not know why.  anyone can help me? thanks

I still don't known why, but I stored the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m and GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h files and just copy them under ios/Runner, then it can be build...
